# How to list all intermediate steps of evaluation in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, eval

For example if there's the expression:

```
(map (lambda(x) (add1 x)) '(1 2 3))
```

It evaluates to:

```
'(2 3 4)
```

How to display all the intermediate steps which in this case will be:

```
(map (lambda(x) (add1 x)) '(2 2 3))
(map (lambda(x) (add1 x)) '(2 3 3))
```

Comment: [racket tracer](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/debugging.html)

Comment: Try the Algebraic Stepper.
An example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39549417/understanding-scheme-function/39549516#39549516

Comment: racket tracer doesn't seem to show the whole expression, and the algebraic stepper is a manual tool. What's needed is something that will show all the intermediate expressions by simply applying a function.

Comment: It seems like you think `map` somehow updated the source list. It does not. The intermediate steps if you traced `map` would be `(cons 2 (map (lambda (x) (add1 x)) '(2 3))` and `(cons 2 (cons 3  (map (lambda (x) (add1 x)) '(3))))`. The stepper in the learning languages might do this, but the debugger is also very useful.

Comment: Actually, the algebraic stepper *does* contain code that will emit all of the steps at once. It's been a while since it was used or tested. Perhaps you can elaborate on what exactly you need it for?

Comment: I want to create an animation of evaluation. For example map flying over list and modyfying it, tree-map process modifying a tree and forking (splitting into multiple functions)  at each node that has 2 or more children. Iota spitting out numbers. Tree generators growing trees and tree-folds folding them ("trees breathing"). Humans are used to the 3d world around them "living" not static text. Wouldn't it improve code understanding if we could see it this way? Any ideas of which functions you'd like to see animated?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this would be to start by making your own lambda calculus interpreter and adding the extra scheme features you need, and then modifying that interpreter to produce the execution trace that you want.

This could get you started with writing an interpreter http://matt.might.net/articles/implementing-a-programming-language/